# Any orientable connected two dimensional compact manifold is homeomorphic to a sphere with handles

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, surfaces

I've heard that the statement in the title is a "classical" result. Can someone point me a book or an exposition article with proof? I want to get to that result as easy and cleanly as possible.

Comment: The statement is called the classification of surfaces. There's a famous expository article of Francis & Weeks covering Conway's ZIP proof of the theorem.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks.